# How to erase values in a map with a struct? [C++]

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, erase

Im working in a small TCP client-server, and i use 'map' with a struct to store the client tracking number his ip and his socket.
And the main problem is, when i want to delete his data from the 'map' (Connection closed) it does, but when it comes 2 or more clients it seems the server got lag and later, when 1 or more clients closes his connection, the server app stops responding (but accepting connections)... maybe stops in a infinite loop?
Anyways... here is my code:

```
//------------------------------
//--------------- main.h

struct ClientData{
    int sock;
    char IP [65];
};

class ServerNetwork
{
public:
    map<int, ClientData> MapClient;
...


//------------------------------
//--------------- ServerNetwork.cpp

void ServerNetwork::SendToAll(char * packets, int totalSize)
{
    SOCKET currentSocket;
    map<int, ClientData>::iterator iter;
    int iSendResult;
    if (MapClient.empty()){
        return;
    }
    for (iter = MapClient.begin(); iter != MapClient.end(); iter++ )
    {
        int currentID = iter->first;
        currentSocket = iter->second.sock;
        iSendResult = SendInfo(currentSocket, packets, totalSize);

        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(currentSocket);
            printf("Closed Connection from Client # %d\n", currentID);
            RemoveClient(currentID);
            iter = sessions.begin();
            iter++;
            break;
        }
        iter++;
    }
}

void ServerNetwork::RemoveClient(int ClientID)
{
    MapClient.erase(ClientID);
    printf("Deleted!\n");
}
```

MapClient holds client ID+(ClientSock&ClientIP)
I'm using VisualStudio 2013.

Thanks!

Comment: @YuHao This is actually biology ;)

Comment: You should probably close the sockets when you are erasing them from the MAP. You could add a destructor to the client data struct to take care of that...

Comment: are you using multiple threads?

Comment: @Arkadiyi Well, actually one thread that calls that function of 'SendToAll' to send 1 byte to perform some kind of "Keep Alive" every 10 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You should really take advantage of the fact that Map::erase returns the next iterator after the erase. So refactoring the erase into removeclient is a bad idea.

```
iter=MapClient.begin()
while(iter != MapClient.end()
{
   ....
   if(...)
   {       
      closesocket(currentSocket);
      printf...
      iter = MapClient.erase(iter);
      continue; //do this to avoid the iter++ below
   }
   iter++;    
}
```

Comment: After doing this:
The sever accepts all incoming clients and when some one of them quits, it stops again...
It's still somehow the same problem.

Comment: When does it stop? Before or after the printf?

Comment: Are there other threads that is iterating trough the map? If so, make sure to lock the map with mutexes before erasing from the map.

Comment: Well, actually i put the printf after the erase to see if it pass the test XD and yes... shows the printf and sends info if some of they still's online, and when some of them quits, the server stops.
There is just one thread that calls the send every 10 sec... that's all, just the call

Comment: using debug mode shows me this error:
list iterator not incrementable

Comment: Have you included the 'continue' statement i showed? The list iterator is not incrementable message comes when you are trying to increment the end-iterator.

Comment: this is the exact error: 

Expression: map/set iterator not incrementable

Now im thinking about making a thread server based, to avoid this kind of problems :/

Comment: To be more expecific:
1- Server Starts and make a thread for calling the 'keep-alive packet' (SendToAll) so, it will try to find a client on map and if there is no client, nothing happens.
2- Once a client connects, saves his data on the map and the thread calls the 'SenToAll' if there is a client, send the packet.
3- If the client keeps online, server acts normal and can accept more clients and keeps sending the 'keep-alive packet'
4- If some client closes connection, erase data from map, and then the error comes up!